# Access nested hasttables by its key

Tags: powershell

I try do work with nested hashtables to get a specific value (number). 
The hashtable looks like the following.

```
$Hashtable = @{
    'Feature1' = @{
        'Audit'  = 1
        'Block'  = 2
        'Change' = 3
    }
    'Feature2' = @{
        'Audit'  = 4
        'Block'  = 5
        'Change' = 3
    }
}
```

I want to access the hashtable with a lookup by key.
The first example works just fine.

```
$Hashtable['Feature1']['Audit', 'Block']
1
2
```

Specifying multiple keys works fine, too.

```
$Hashtable['Feature1', 'Feature2']

Name                           Value
----                           ---- -
Block                          2
Change                         3
Audit                          1
Block                          5
Change                         3
Audit                          4
```

However, if I specify multiple keys in the first hashtable, it seems that I cannot access the nested hashtable.

```
$Hashtable['Feature1', 'Feature2']['Block', 'Audit']
```

Expected output would be `2`, `1`, `5` and `4`, but instead I get `$null`.

I do have a workaround. If I loop through the first result, I get the expected result.

```
$Hashtable['Feature1', 'Feature2'] | % {$_['Block', 'Audit']}
2
1
5
4
```

I just wonder if there is 1) a nicer way to do that and 2) why I have to loop in that example.

I wished I could access the hashtable like `$Hashtable[$Features][$Actions]` where both variables are an array of keys.

Comment: In my opinion the nicer way is to use a hash where the values are custom objects.

Answer (score 2):

```
$Hashtable['Feature1', 'Feature2'].Block
```

`$Hashtable['Feature1', 'Feature2']` is an array, and the `array.Property` notation is a shorthand for selecting a single property for all elements of an array (requires PowerShell v3 or newer).

Edit: The above approach only works when you need a single key. If you need multiple, I can't think of any way to skip iterating over the inner hashtables. Selecting multiple keys at once (e.g. `$Hashtable['Feature1', 'Feature2']`) can only be done on hashtables, not arrays, and returns an array, so it can't be chained.

Comment: Elegant solution. I don't have v2 to look at right now but I'm pretty sure this will only work v3+. Could be wrong though.

Comment: You're right, that works. I'm afraid I didn't ask my question specific enough though. My orignal plan was, that I can access both hashtables with an array of keys. I'll update my question accordingly.